# how to read Sent Mails of gmail using javaxmail android

Tags: android, gmail-imap, jakarta-mail

How can I get mails from Sent Mail folder of gmail? I can get mails from inbox using

```
store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", user, password);
Folder folder = store.getFolder("Inbox");
```

I have tried,

```
Folder folder = store.getFolder("Sent");
//and
Folder folder = store.getFolder("AllMail");
```

but none of this is working, I'm getting a `FolderNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GMail folders for Sent, Drafts and so on, are prefixed with the tag `[Gmail]`, so for the Sent Mail, it would be accessed like so:

```
Folder folder = store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Sent Mail");
```

Link:
[Gmail folders in your mail client](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=82367)